# Is there any theorem/physical law with different names in more than two different languages/regions?

Tags: mathematics, physics, big-list

Mathematical statements and physics equations often are named after a person (like Pythagoras theorem or Newton's second law). Reading from different authors with different origins one may sometimes find a common statement with a different name. I have usually seen this in French and Russian sources, where Snell's law became Descartes' law and Gauss' theorem became Ostrogradsky's theorem respectively.

Is there a law/theorem well known for having many different names/authors depending on the language/region? I am looking for more than 2 names/languages/regions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that what you asking for is not so rare, for example the "[Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)" is

1. Rouché–Capelli theorem in English speaking countries, Italy, Brazil and Japan;
2. Kronecker–Capelli theorem in Austria, Poland, Romania and Russia;
3. Rouché–Fontené theorem in France;
4. Rouché–Frobenius theorem in Spain and many countries in Latin America;
5. Frobenius theorem in the Czech Republic and in Slovakia.

Another example, certainly less conspicuous, is the "[law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)" that in France is the *théorème d'Al-Kashi* (but also *loi des cosinus* is common), and "generalized Pythagorean theorem" in many countries where the two names coexist (in France again, but also in Italy).

Answer (score 5):

The richest example in this regard according to me is the **WKB** approximation. WKB approximation, which is technically not a theorem but a recipe for obtaining approximate solutions to the time-independent Schrodinger equation, is named after Wentzel, Kramers and Brillouin. However, the technique is called by different names by/at different people/places:

1. In Holland, it is called the **KWB**.
2. In France, it is called the **BWK**.
3. In England, it is called the **JWKB** with 'J' standing for Jeffreys.
4. In the scientific community it is also known by the name **LG** or **Liouville–Green** method.

Comment: I've also seen BKW, and suspect that all 6 permutations of W,K,B are used. Plus a J in front or in the back.

Answer (score 2):

[Cauchy, Schwarz and Bunyakovski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) names are used in French, Russian and English speaking countries, along with various combinations of these names.

The names  [Weierstrass, Casorati and Sochocki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) are variously associated with
one theorem (which was really stated for the first time by Briot and Bouquet).

[Another theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) of Sochoski is variousuly credited to Plemelj or to
[Kramers and Kronig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations). (Only Russian speakers call it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The [**Ludolphian number**](http://www.calculatoredge.com/math/mathhistory/historyans27.htm) (as it is known in Germany—at least it was up to 100 years ago) is called $\pi$ in English-language texts.  It was called the Ludolphian number recognizing that Ludolph Van Ceulen calculated it to 35 decimal places in the sixteenth century.

Comment: The question is about things that have at least three names.

Comment: $\pi$ is also called "Archimedes's constant" ([see](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pi.html)), so we have three names for it...

Comment: That's for the moment not in your answer also in which language is it called that aside from English?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good example in the way it is written now, as π is the symbol and "Ludolphian number" the (antiquated) name. All constants have both a name and a symbol (Euler's number = e) which don't even have to be based in a person (imaginary unit = i, Gravity constant = G etc.).

Comment: It's now generally called "Kreiszahl" ("circle number") or "Kreiszahl Pi" in German, so it does have alternative names.